# Erro ao gerar APK arquivo values do Google Analytics

Tags: android

Estou tendo um problema no google analytics quando vou gerar a APK esta sendo demonstrado a seguinte mensagem de erro.

```
.../app/build/generated/res/google-services/release/values/values.xml
Error:(3) Error: "ga_trackingId" is not translated in "pt" (Portuguese) [MissingTranslation]
Error:(4) Error: "gcm_defaultSenderId" is not translated in "pt" (Portuguese) [MissingTranslation]
Error:(5) Error: "google_app_id" is not translated in "pt" (Portuguese) [MissingTranslation]
```

Grato.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, acredito que como estou usando mais de um idioma (Ingles e Português) foi necessário adicionar na pasta values-pt o arquivo values do google analytics.

Comment: você está correto. Quando se trabalha com mais idiomas os 2 arquivos devem conter o mesmo número de strings. Adicione o seu comentário como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido, acredito que como estou usando mais de um idioma (Ingles e Português) foi necessário adicionar na pasta values-pt o arquivo values do google analytics.